# How do you compile an SDL2-2.0.16 release to make libsdl264.dll.a and libsdl264.main.a (not libsdl2...)?

Tags: dll, sdl, cross-compiling, sdl-2, lib

Sorry for not being clear I don't understand a lot on these.
I'm trying to compile an [SDL2-2.0.16](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.16.zip) release to make libsdl264.dll.a and libsdl264.main.a to put theses in the library folder for ioquake3 to make the binary recognizes sdl264.dll and does not look for sdl2.dll.
I've already searched for a solution and find this : https://github.com/ioquake/ioq3/issues/528 but I don't understand the line : "edit Makefile.in and change TARGET, SDLMAIN_TARGET and SDLTEST_TARGET s/libSDL2/libSDL264/".
Because I've tried to simply replace libsdl2 by libsdl264 in the makefile.in but it don't work (I'm cross compiling with mingw32).
Maybe i've done this badly or maybe I use a bad release, I don't know.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Why recompile SDL, just rename its DLL. I just tried to cross-compile it myself, and got the opposite problem: it produced `SDL264.dll`, but was looking for `SDL2.dll`. If anything, I'd patch the makefiles of this project rather than SDL2.

Comment: I didn't specify it because I didn't think it had anything to do with the problem, but I want to put an x86 binary and an x86_64 binary in the same folder and I can't as long as the dlls have the same name. The problem does not come from the makefile I'm sure about that but from the libraries, I tried to take libraries from elsewhere and it worked but I want to compile myself for a question of license and version of sdl2. Maybe I misspoke but that's what I meant, the project produces a sdl264.dll and is looking for a sdl2.dll and changing the libraries solves the problem but I don't know how.

Comment: It work taking libraries from here : https://github.com/iortcw/iortcw/tree/master/SP/code/libs/win64 but I don't want 2.0.18 and GPL3 but 2.0.16 and GPL2 and in any case I would like to do it myself for my project 

Comment: Because if I rename it into sdl2.dll it will overwrite the sdl2.dll of the x86 binary and I want both in the same directory. x86 binary don't launch if it's the sdl264.dll renamed into sdl2.dll and x86_64 don't launch if it's the sdl2.dll of the x86. anyway I know how to do myself to rename dlls, that's not why I asked the question. I really think we have to do what the guy from github said but I don't quite understand. I feel dumb talking to myself now your question is gone

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realized my mistake and deleted the comment just before you replied.

Comment: Don't worry I'm already glad you're interested in my problem

Comment: I've messed around with it, and I concur that it requires patching SDL2 build scripts. To be honest, I think it's not worth the time, I'd just drop x32 support or ship it in a different folder.

Comment: but some people ask for 32 bit support and if I drop it it a different folder I must dupplicate my game files and it will be too heavy . I'm gonna continue looking how to modify the makefile.in. I'm sure it's the solution I just don't understand "s/libSDL2/libSDL264/"

Comment: `s/libSDL2/libSDL264/` just means "replace (the first occurence of) `libSDL2` with `libSDL264`". It's a `sed` command, which became a shorthand for telling someone to replace one string with the other by any means, not necessarily `sed`. Unsure if "the first occurence only" is intended or just a sloppy command writing. *"some people ask for 32 bit support"* Tell them to update their OSes. Liking retro games is one thing, but sitting on an outdated OS and whining about applications dropping support is silly.

Comment: Already it helps me a lot thank you, I will still continue to search I have to know 

Comment: If someone asking, just follow the instrutions of the github guy and everything should work perfectly, I had problem because I'm dumb.